# Mysterious .bk file in OS X

Tags: macos, git, textwrangler

I am trying to move some files in a git repository that I have in my Macbook (OS X 10.11.4). However, when I try to do a `git mv`, I get this:

```
fatal: bad source, source=remote_plugins/insertbooking_invoice.class.php.bk, destination=foo/remote_plugins/insertbooking_invoice.class.php.bk
```

This has happened to me in the past; whenever I tried to do a commit using Sourcetree (a GUI git client), it always complained about stray `.bk` files that came out of nowhere.

Now... the problem is that, when I try to delete the `.bk` file in question, I can't find it anywhere:

- With Terminal, I try a `ls -la` and don't see it.
- With Finder, I try to make it show hidden files with the 
  `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` trick, and I don't see it.
- If I try to just delete it using `rm`, it says that the file doesn't exist.

I use TextWrangler as an editor, so I thought that it would be a backup file created by it; however, I haven't been able to find any documentation about this.

Any ideas? Is there any new super-hidden type of file that Apple has introduced in later versions of OS X and that I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the files are/might be coming from exactly, but I understand that `git mv` will fail if there are any untracked or unstaged files in the move [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900805/git-command-to-move-a-folder-inside-another). You can quickly see if you have unstaged changes by running `git status`.

If yes, you could stage all changes with `git add -A`, and then run `git mv`, or, if you believe all changes to be committed, you could delete any untracked/not ignored files with `git clean -f`, then attempt `git mv`. If you suspect that TextWrangler is creating the `.bk` files, you'll probably want to close it to prevent the files being recreated while you move the directory.